Struggling to deploy FastAPI + PostgreSQL with docker compose on ECS (Essential container exiting without logs)
I’m facing a persistent issue while trying to deploy my FastAPI + PostgreSQL app using docker compose on AWS ECS Fargate. Despite multiple debugging attempts, I can’t seem to get it working properly. The exit code is 0, which means no errors, but the container stops right after starting.
I have no problem running the dockerized FastAPI and PostgreSQL on my local machine, but it takes substantial time (~8 min) to load the ColPali model from huggingface and start using the API endpoints.
When I deploy the app to ECS, the essential container exits immediately. No logs are generated in CloudWatch (despite having included awslogs, container insights, etc.), and debugging has been a nightmare. I have made sure to include necessary permissions including policy for ecsTaskExecutionRole, s3:GetObject, policy for ECR access.
I have been following the workflow here https://beabetterdev.com/2023/01/29/ecs-fargate-tutorial-with-fastapi/, with which I was able to deploy a simple FastAPI with a couple of endpoints and no other dependencies successfully.

I use aws cli to create a repository, build, tag, and push the Docker image.

I create a cluster with default settings.

I create a new task definition with Task Role of ecsTaskExecutionRole, Linux/ARM64 (as I'm using Mac M2 chip), and environment variables through S3.

Under Clusters, I also run a new task under Tasks with mostly default settings.


At this point, I don't know what to do. Any help will be very much appreciated!!
Updated
Task definition json
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:<>:task-definition/colpali-search:1",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "colpali-search-api",
            "image": "<>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/colpali-search:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "colpali-search-port",
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [
                {
                    "value": "arn:aws:s3:::colpali-search-bucket/.env",
                    "type": "s3"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/colpali-search",
                    "mode": "non-blocking",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "colpali-search",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 1,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.env-files.s3"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2024-12-03T18:09:53.720Z",
    "registeredBy": "",
    "tags": []
}

docker-compose.yml
services:
    fastapi:
        build: .
        container_name: colpali-search
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
        networks:
            - app-network
        volumes:
            - ./:/code:ro
        env_file:
            - .env
        environment:
            - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
            - PYTHONPATH=/code
        ports:
            - '8000:8000'
        command: >
            sh -c "alembic upgrade head && fastapi run app.py --port 8000 --workers 4"

    db:
        image: pgvector/pgvector:pg17
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
            - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        networks:
            - app-network
        env_file:
            - .env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        entrypoint: sh -c "chmod 644 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql && docker-entrypoint.sh postgres"
        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                    'CMD-SHELL',
                    'pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}',
                ]
            interval: 5s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
networks:
    app-network:

volumes:
    postgres_data:

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12-slim as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y poppler-utils && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV  POETRY_VERSION=1.6.1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"


FROM base as builder
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache \
    pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_HOME/pypoetry/cache \
    poetry install --no-dev


FROM base as production
ENV FASTAPI_ENV=production
COPY --from=builder $VENV_PATH $VENV_PATH
COPY ./colpali_search /colpali_search
COPY .env /colpali_search/
COPY alembic.ini /colpali_search/
COPY alembic /colpali_search/alembic
WORKDIR /colpali_search
EXPOSE 8000


Docker Compose support for deployments to ECS was removed quite a while ago. I also don't see any mention of Docker Compose on that website you linked to. Given the description of the steps you have taken in your question, it also does not appear that you are actually using Docker Compose.

It would be helpful if you added the Task Definition JSON to your question, so we could see the details of the task you are trying to run. If you are actually using Docker Compose, then adding the docker-compose.yml file to your question would be appropriate as well.

Thank you @MarkB! I just added the Task Definition JSOn along with my Docker files.

OK so all the stuff about Docker Compose in your question seems completely irrelevant. You aren't using Docker Compose on AWS, you are only using it locally. And you aren't running PostgreSQL on ECS either, like your question indicates. I assume you are running PostgreSQL some other way like RDS, which would be the correct way to run PostgreSQL on AWS.

You are right that I'm only running Docker Compose locally and not on AWS. I wanted to get both FastAPI and PostgreSQL running similar to my local setting, but as you pointed out it might be best to deploy Postgre on RDS. I will work on it later today.

You don't have a COMMAND defined in your Dockerfile.
You do have a command defined in the docker-compose.yml file.
You don't have a command defined in the ECS task definition.
Given the content of your question, it appears you are confused about when you are using Docker Compose and when you are not. You are only using Docker Compose when you run the docker-compose command locally. You are not running Docker Compose on AWS and the contents of your docker-compose.yml file do not affect anything in your AWS environment. The AWS ECS Task Definition serves the same purpose on AWS as the docker-compose.yml file does in your local environment.
The only place you have defined a command for your docker image to run is in the docker-compose.yml file that is only used when you run your application locally. With your current configuration, I think the command will be inherited from the base docker image python:3.12-slim which just runs python with no arguments and exits. This is most likely why you are getting a quick container exit with no logs after deploying your ECS task.

Thank you so much for the thoughtful response! You are absolutely right that I'm still confused about how each component interacts with each other. Would you suggest to only use Dockerfile (not bothering with Docker Compose) and add command to ECS task definition? Please feel free to suggest other resources that I can look into!

I would absolutely keep using Docker Compose locally. To fix the issue on AWS, I would add the command to the Task Definition. Your other comment sounds like you don't actually have a PostgreSQL database running yet on AWS, so I would start by setting that up in RDS, and adding the connection parameters as environment variables to the ECS task definition.
